# Android project with multiple so files in different ndk versions

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an Android project with lots of so files which are built by third party. I wonder if it is OK when they build these so files by different ndk versions. And how does android device know which ndk version should be used to run these so files?

Answer (score 1):

The NDK version only determines which header files are available at compile time (eg "asset_manager.h").
These header files in turn define some required functions ("AAssetManager_openDir"), which -- if you use them -- will result in dynamic symbol dependencies in your final library.

A device with a given Android version contains libraries with all the dynamic symbols for the versions up to that NDK version.

So to answer your first question: it does not matter, everything should just work.